# Why is a space being added after a Japanese period in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML, and I was running into a little bit of an issue with a couple of lines of text not being center-aligned correctly.  The lines were nothing more than simple text, separate by a line break tag, within a link tag with the `text-align: center` style being applied to it from a css file.  These were the two lines:

```
キリスト教は
何ですか。
```

The problem was that the second line was showing up on the page a little off-center; it was a few pixels closer to the left than it was to the right.  However I could still see that the page was actually trying to center it.  Within a few minutes of experimenting with it, I tried this bit of HTML out:

```
<html xml:lang="ja" lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p style="text-align: center;">キリスト教は<br />何ですか。</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Same problem.  Even though the second line is centered on the page, you can tell that it's not done right.  I copied and pasted it into Word, and I saw that an extra space was being added after the period (。) on that line.  After removing the period from the HTML, the thing centered perfectly.  I tried manually typing the period back in, but that just re-inserted the space along with the period on the actual page.

?  Nobody's telling the HTML to do this.  I can't imagine why this would even be a default setting.  How do you get rid of it?  I'm saving the file in UTF-8, and I'm using Firefox.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character itself is off-center; there is built in space on the right side of it.

[image: Ideographic Full Stop]

Comment: Lol.  Selecting text off of there - or especially in Word - made it look like an actual character was placed off to the side.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet of Japanese unicode [from this site](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml):

```
Japanese-style punctuation ( 3000 - 303f)
  3000   　  、  。  〃  〄  々  〆  〇  〈  〉  《  》  「  」  『  』 
  3010   【  】  〒  〓  〔  〕  〖  〗  〘  〙  〚  〛  〜  〝  〞  〟 
  3020   〠  〡  〢  〣  〤  〥  〦  〧  〨  〩  〪  〫  〬  〭  〮  〯 
  3030   〰  〱  〲  〳  〴  〵  〶  〷  〸  〹  〺  〻  〼  〽  〾  〿
```

Now look at it with code highlighting here `。`. The character itself is `U+3002` also known as [`IDEOGRAPHIC FULL STOP`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3002/index.htm). The space is officially part of the character itself.